# My implementation of app indexing is not working

Tags: android, firebase, android-manifest, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

Here is my activity structure: SplashActivity -> MainActivity. My MainActivity has a Spinner that is populated from ContentProvider. Based on Spinner selection, I present different content to the user. The content map perfectly to the content on my website. My website has long been indexed and is working fine. Now I want to index said content in my app.

**Here is my manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
      android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value=".activities.MainActivity"/>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
      android:host="www.business.com"
      android:scheme="http"/>
    <data
      android:host="www.business.com"
      android:scheme="https"/>
    <data
      android:host="business.com"
      android:scheme="http"/>
    <data
      android:host="business.com"
      android:scheme="https"/>
    <data
      android:host="/*"
      android:scheme="business"/>
    <data android:scheme="android-app"
        android:host="com.business.android" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Here is the app-indexing portion of my MainActivity**

```
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    appIndexingTask();
  }

  private void appIndexingTask() {
    new AsyncTask() {

      @Override
      protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        try {
          if(null == mNdxClient){
            mNdxClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .enableAutoManage(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this)
                .addApi(AppInvite.API).addApi(AppIndex.API)
                .build();
          }
          if(!mNdxClient.isConnected()){
            mNdxClient.blockingConnect();
          }
          if (mNdxClient != null && mNdxClient.isConnected()) {
            HashMap<Uri, Action> indexedActions = new HashMap<>();

            List<Content> contentList = getAllFromContentProvider();
            for(Content c: contentList){
              Uri uri = Uri.parse(FirebaseUtils.appIndexingLink(c.getUrl()));
              Action action = getAction(c.getName(), c.getDescription(), uri);
              AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(mNdxClient, action);
              indexedActions.put(uri, action);
            }


            for (Action action : indexedActions.values()) {
              AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(mNdxClient, indexedActions.get(action));
            }
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          //abandon task
        }
        return null;
      }

      public Action getAction(String title, String description, Uri uri) {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
            .setName(title)
            .setDescription(description)
            .setUrl(uri)
            .build();

         return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
            .setObject(object)
            .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
            .build();

      }
    }.execute();

  }
```

Here is the Utility method

```
  public static String appIndexingLink(String urlString){
    String appNdx= new StringBuilder("android-app://").append(BASE_URL).append(urlString).toString();
    return appNdx;
  }
```

Finally, in gradle I am using

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'//project level

//app level
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.0.0"
```

Some important points

- App-Invite works: I can send an invite and then open the invite (code not shown)
- Deep Linking works, if I send myself a link to my site, when I open the link on my android phone, it opens it with the app perfectly.
- Google Search has **not** indexed my app
- Fetch as Google fails with “URI unsupported” whether I point to Play Store or local apk.

Notice the filter

```
<data android:scheme="android-app"
        android:host="com. business.android" />
```

I don’t see it anywhere in documentations. But nothing else works. So I added it. It’s still not working.

Although I am not showing logging. I am logging and so I know that the app-indexing code runs.

Comment: It seems to me like you never gave the device permission to even access the internet.

Comment: can you please try with autoverify tag in filter `<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">`

Comment: Could you post the error message for  “URI unsupported”?